# When I apply approx_fprime to scipy.minimize, it doesn't iterate

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, minimize

I tried using minimize function in scipy packages like below code
When I use `jac option = approx_fprime`, iteration is 0 and optimization doesn't work.
But When I use `jac option = rosen_der`, it worked!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, approx_fprime


def rosen(x):
    """The Rosenbrock function"""
    return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)

def rosen_der(x): 
    # derivative of rosenbrock function
    xm = x[1:-1]
    xm_m1 = x[:-2]
    xm_p1 = x[2:]
    der = np.zeros_like(x)
    der[1:-1] = 200*(xm-xm_m1**2) - 400*(xm_p1 - xm**2)*xm - 2*(1-xm)
    der[0] = -400*x[0]*(x[1]-x[0]**2) - 2*(1-x[0])
    der[-1] = 200*(x[-1]-x[-2]**2)
    return der
```

```
x0=np.array([1.3, 0.7])
```

```
eps = np.sqrt(np.finfo(float).eps)
fprime = lambda x : np.array(approx_fprime(x0, rosen, eps))
```

```
res = minimize(rosen, x0, method='CG', jac=fprime, options={'maxiter':10, 'disp': True})
```

```
print(res.x)
```

```
[ 515.40001106 -197.99999905]
[ 515.4 -198. ]
98.10000000000005
Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
         Current function value: 98.100000
         Iterations: 0
         Function evaluations: 33
         Gradient evaluations: 21
[1.3 0.7]
```

I checked approx_fprime is ndarray, same rosen_der, and value is same too.
Why optimization doesn't work??

Answer (score 1):

Your function `fprime` is a function of `x` but approximates the derivative at `x0`. Consequently, you're evaluating the gradient at the initial guess `x0` in every iteration. You should evaluate/approximate the derivative at `x` instead:

```py
fprime = lambda x : approx_fprime(x, rosen, eps)
```

Note that `approx_fprime` already returns an np.ndarray, so there's no need for the extra np.array call.

It's also worth mentioning that you don't need to pass approximated derivatives as `minimize` approximates them by finite differences by default once you don't pass any derivatives, i.e. `jac=None`. However, `minimize` uses [`approx_derivative`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/502df0ece7eb9525de8a7f243044b3fe18ad5cca/scipy/optimize/_numdiff.py#L275) under the hood instead of approx_fprime as it provides support for evaluating derivatives at variable bounds.

Comment: Oh dear... cheers Joni : ) it work!